# Why does AudioSource not initializes itself?

Tags: unity, audio, initialization

Why does AudioSource not initializes itself?

Here is my code:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraConfig : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject objToFollow;

    public bool followRabbit;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        followRabbit = true;
        LevelController.current.cameraWhichLooksForRabbit = this;

        setMusicSource();
        setSoundSources();
    }

    public AudioClip music, rabbitWalksSound, rabbitDiesSound, rabbitFallsSound, enemyAttacksSound;
    private AudioSource musicSrc, rabbitWalksSrc, rabbitDiesSrc, rabbitFallsSrc, enemyAttacksSrc;

    private void setMusicSource()
    {setClipForSrc(musicSrc, music, true);}

    private void setSoundSources()
    {
        setClipForSrc(rabbitWalksSrc, rabbitWalksSound, false);
        setClipForSrc(rabbitDiesSrc, rabbitDiesSound, false);
        setClipForSrc(rabbitFallsSrc, rabbitFallsSound, false);
        setClipForSrc(enemyAttacksSrc, enemyAttacksSound, false);
    }

    private void setClipForSrc(AudioSource src, AudioClip clip, bool loop)
    {
        src = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
        src.clip = clip;
        src.loop = loop;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        checkMusicAndStopOrStartIfNecessary();

        if (!followRabbit)
        { return; }

        Transform rabit_transform = objToFollow.transform;
        Transform camera_transform = this.transform;

        Vector3 rabit_position = rabit_transform.position;
        Vector3 camera_position = camera_transform.position;

        camera_position.x = rabit_position.x;
        camera_position.y = rabit_position.y;

        camera_transform.position = camera_position;
    }

    public void playSoundRabbitWalks()
    {
        if (!rabbitWalksSrc.isPlaying)
        { rabbitWalksSrc.Play(); }
    }

    public void playSoundRabbitDies()
    { rabbitDiesSrc.Play(); }

    public void playSoundRabbitFalls()
    { rabbitFallsSrc.Play(); }

    public void playSoundEnemyAttacks()
    { enemyAttacksSrc.Play(); }

    public void stopSoundRabbitWalks()
    {
        if (rabbitWalksSrc.isPlaying)
        { rabbitWalksSrc.Stop(); }
    }

    public void stopSoundRabbitDies()
    { rabbitDiesSrc.Stop(); }

    public void stopSoundRabbitFalls()
    {rabbitFallsSrc.Stop();}

    public void stopSoundEnemyAttacks()
    {
        enemyAttacksSrc.Stop();
    }

    private void checkMusicAndStopOrStartIfNecessary()
    {
        if (SoundManager.Instance.isMusicOn() && !musicSrc.isPlaying)
        { musicSrc.Play(); }
        else if(!SoundManager.Instance.isMusicOn() && musicSrc.isPlaying)
        { musicSrc.Stop(); }
    }
}
```

Here are screenshot of the exceptions in console and inspector view:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AudioSource` is a class, which means it is a reference type. The default value of a reference type that is declared without initialization

```
SomeReferenceType someThing;
```

is null. That's how C# works.

Even if it were *possible* for `AudioSource` to "initialize itself" when declared the way you are declaring them, how would it know what to initialize itself *with*? `AudioSource` is about playing back audio clips, so an individual audio source needs to know which clip to play, et cetera.

You need to either explicitly initialize your `AudioSource` instances in your code (`musicSrc = new AudioSource(...)` and so on) or expose them to the inspector and set them there. It sort of looks like that latter option is what you *expected* to be doing, given the screenshot of the inspector in your original screenshots, but what you've shown there is exposure and initialization of the audio *clips*. Not the sources.

---

Actually, it looks like you expected `setClipForSrc` to do this initialization for you, but if that's what you want you need to pass the clip using [`ref`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref):

```
private void setClipForSrc(ref AudioSource src, AudioClip clip, bool loop)
{
    src = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();
    src.clip = clip;
    src.loop = loop;
}
```

and then call it as `setClipForSrc(ref musicSrc, ...)`. Without `ref`, what you are doing is simply reseating the local reference inside the function to refer to a new value, you are not actually changing what the member variable references `musicSrc` et cetera refer to. This would work if all you wanted to do is call functions on `src` or otherwise mutate it, but if you to completely re-assign it to point to a new object, and you want that re-assignment to propagate beyond the function `setClipForSrc`, you need to pass the reference `src` by reference itself, using the `ref` keyword.

Comment: Okay. But is not it is the part of the code which does all the needed initialization: `src = gameObject.AddComponent<AudioSource>();`?

Comment: Yes, I see that now that you switched to code I could search instead of screenshots. You're doing something else wrong in that function, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @ohidano I've added more information.

Comment: it strange, but why your name is not offered as an option when I type `@Jos` in comments? Anyway it seems like you added a lot of cool info and I am going to read it all right now! Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: @ohidano Because I will be pinged automatically by any comment on my answer, the site won't let you auto-complete my name in a comment on my answer, I guess, since it isn't necessary to ping me.

Comment: Okay. I am going to give it a try right now! Hope it will work! <3

Comment: Common! It is veeery cool! It worked out! Like it thanks SO for such an amazing help!